# how react Context is working with useState hook and how its value being update?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
import { createContext,useState } from "react"
    
export const UserContext= createContext({
        currentUser:null,
        SetCurrentUser:()=>null
})

export const UserProvider = ({children})=> {
const [currentUser,setCurrentUser]=useState(null)
```

what this value is doing here and how its updating that `useState` hook how its passing value as the value is an object here, please explain the whole code

```
const value = {currentUser,setCurrentUser};
    return <UserContext.Provider value={value} > {children} </UserContext.Provider>
}
```

Comment: I think something is mixed up here. This would make perfect sense if the `currentState` key in the context was renamed `currentuser` and the `currentUser` one was `setCurrentUser`. Then any component inside your `UserProvider` would both have access to the `currentUser` value and also each would be able to update that value as desired via `setCurrentUser`.

Answer (score 0):

`createContext(defaultValue)` would create a context with `defaultValue` but that `defaultValue` is only used if the context is accessed outside of its provider. If we access the same context from inside its provider, then the provider `value` will be used.

Answer (score 0):

Well, when you use context you basically expose a value for all children of the context. In your case the exposed value is an JS Object which contains your state setter and the state value, so when you want to change the state you will change the value, u can use something like this:

```
const { currentUser, setCurrentUser } = React.useContext(UserContext);

setCurrentUser(your_value);
```

or :

```
setCurrentUser(prev => ({
   ...prev,
   [key]: new_key_object;
}));
```

But, your approach is a little bit nonoptimal because setState will trigger a rerender for each change, i strongly recommend to use [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) hook, otherwise memoise ([useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo), [memo](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/memo)) the child components